# I need to get the Direct Messages one by one using twitter api

Tags: php, twitter

What I am trying to do is a twitter bot for retweeting whatever I have in my DMbox.
So I need a few things.

1. I need to follow all the users who follow me. (I did that)
2. I need to read the DMs( I have to do)
3. Tweet the DM (I can do it i guess)
4. Delete the Read DMS(I dont think I wil be able to do it without help)

The problem with reading DMs are I am getting all the DMs at once. How can I tweet it one by one, I mean how I can take one DM from this Response I am getting for "$_GET['https://api.twitter.com/1/direct_messages.json']"

Now after retweeting all these DMs how can I delete all of them?

Comment: how did you get on with this in the end? I'm trying to do something very similar, is there anyway I could ask for some help with the code? I'm reasonably new to PHP. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the GET direct_messages method provided by the REST API, you can use a combination of the since_id, max_id, and count to request one DM (count) older than (max_id) or more recent than (since_id) some known DM. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/direct_messages

Here is an example: https://api.twitter.com/1/direct_messages.json?count=1&since_id=1270520569

After you have grabbed the DM and thus, received it's id, you can grab your next DM using the above code and delete the current message using the POST direct_messages/destroy/:id method also available through the REST API. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/direct_messages/destroy/%3Aid

Here is an example of the delete method: https://api.twitter.com/1/direct_messages/destroy/1270520569.json

To get the first DM that you use to begin your process of retrieving messages, simply use the GET direct_messages with a count of 1 and move either backwards or forwards (max_id or since_id) depending on how Twitter orders the tweets. If they are not ordered by time, you'll simply have to explore in both directions.

Comment: thanks for that, it really solved my problem. but one more thing.  lets say i have 3 dms in my inbox. How do I know that if completed reading everything an deleted all of them?

Comment: When you use the direct_messages method without any restrictions (since_id or max_id) and receive an empty json object, you know your DM box is empty. If I have answered your question please mark it as answered. Also, if you have any further questions, please post a new question. Thanks!